# Mongoose Docs - Manually Populate Fields

Tags: javascript, mongoose

I am having issues understanding how this code would possibly work.
This is from the mongoose docs:
https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#setting-populated-fields

'story.author' makes sense but 'author' doesn't, where is that value coming from?

```
Story.findOne({ title: 'Casino Royale' }, function(error, story) {
  if (error) {
    return handleError(error);
  }
  story.author = author;
  console.log(story.author.name); // prints "Ian Fleming"
});
```

Comment: That is definitely an unhelpful format for a documentation example (as far as we know `author` is `undefined`). Perhaps you can PR to their docs with a clearer bit of syntax. I wonder if they meant to say `author = story.author`?

Comment: `author` is defined [here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#saving-refs). The documentation assumes that you're reading the entire page, instead of just a snippet.